# Evenly sized Bootstrap columns are not aligning correctly

Tags: html, css

I have 3 evenly sized columns within a bootstrap container class which I would like to display on the same row. (Until they all collapse simultaneously on a smaller screen) Currently, the first two columns align horizontally, but the third is positioned directly below the first. I have spent some time adjusting my CSS and html, but to no avail.

I've browsed for a relevant answer to my question, as I was sure this is quite a simple problem to fix, however I have not been able to find anything. Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

(Bootstrap v4.4.1)

```css
.cmsInterface {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  padding-top: 5em;
  padding-bottom: 5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-4 cmsInterface" id="cms1" align="center">
      <h5><a href=""><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i> Create/Edit a News Article <i class="far fa-edit"></i></a></h5>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 cmsInterface" id="cms2" align="center">
      <h5><a href="eventportal.php"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i> Create/Edit an Event <i class="far fa-calendar-times"></i></a></h5>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 cmsInterface" id="cms3" align="center">
      <h5><a href="staffportal.php"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i> Add/Edit Staff <i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i></a></h5>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

A screenshot of how the code currently looks in a browser:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

columns in boostrap are supposed to stick to each others , to allow margin, you may only use `.col` without a number, and eventually add the `-lg` breakpoint:

example turning :  `<div class="col-lg-4  cmsInterface" id="cms2" align="center">` into  `<div class="col-lg  cmsInterface" id="cms2" align="center"`>

```css
.cmsInterface {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  padding-top: 5em;
  padding-bottom: 5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg cmsInterface" id="cms1" align="center">
      <h5><a href=""><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i> Create/Edit a News Article <i class="far fa-edit"></i></a></h5>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg  cmsInterface" id="cms2" align="center">
      <h5><a href="eventportal.php"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i> Create/Edit an Event <i class="far fa-calendar-times"></i></a></h5>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg  cmsInterface" id="cms3" align="center">
      <h5><a href="staffportal.php"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i> Add/Edit Staff <i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i></a></h5>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Demo : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/OJPrOqW